# How is this JavaScript ternary operator working

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Happy thanksgiving all:

I've been racking my brain around this one for a half hour and can't quite get where the conditionals are kicking in. I think I've got it down, but just wanted to run it by the pros.

```
(i%3)?(i%5)?i:'Buzz':(i%5)?'Fizz':'FizzBuzz'
```

It breaks down to the following:

```
    if ((i%3) == false) {
        if ((i%5) == false) {
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        } else {
            console.log('Fizz');
        }
    } else {
        if ((i%5) == false) {
            console.log("Buzz");
        } else {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
```

And I assume the ternary operator is grouped as per the following (I'm use to seeing ternary operators in the typical **result ? a : b** fashion, so the extra result and conditionals is throwing me)

```
(i%3)?
    //if the condition is not a multiple of 3
    //check if it is a multiple of 5
    //if it isn't, log the number
    //otherwise log "Buzz" 
    (i%5)?i:'Buzz'
    //if the condition is a multiple of 3
    //check if it is a multiple of 5
    :(i%5)?
        //if it is log "Fizz", 
        //otherwise i is a multiple of 3 & 5 -
        //log "FizzBuzz"
        'Fizz':'FizzBuzz
```

I really appreciate any quantifying posts and/or clarification.
Thanks again.

Comment: If you're going to chain ternaries, just put in some clarifying parentheses so as not to worry about operator precedence. As it is, the ternary conditional characters are of equal operator precedence, and are read right-to-left (which probably yields the expected behavior): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator has [right-to-left associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), which means that the expression is the same as

```
(i%3) ? ((i%5) ? i : 'Buzz') : ((i%5) ? 'Fizz' : 'FizzBuzz')
```

Or it breaks down in the following manner

```
1st ? ( 2nd ) : ( 2nd )
```

The fact that the two `2nd` pieces are also ternary has no effect on the process of the first.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator, in the tradition of C, isn't really `var ? var : var`. It is in fact:

```
statement ? statement : statement
```

Which means, in place of a variable or value you can put code in there to evaluate and the return value of that code is taken as the value. So,

```
(i%3)?(i%5)?i:'Buzz':(i%5)?'Fizz':'FizzBuzz'
```

breaks down as:

```
(i%3) ?
         (i%5) ?
                  i
               :
                  'Buzz'
      :
         (i%5) ?
                  'Fizz'
               :
                  'FizzBuzz'
```

*(basically what you wrote in your question, so your interpretation is correct)*

It helps putting the `:` in separate lines so you can see the pattern. I've also aligned the `?` with the `:` to see which is grouped with which.

Comment: IMHO, nested ternary operators that is written in a single line is evil.

Comment: `condition ? true_statement : false_statement;` would be more semantic.

Comment: `condition_statement` since the condition itself can be a statement. However, I assumed the OP already understand that the syntax is `cond?true:false` I ommitted the semantics to make clear most people's misunderstanding of what data ternary operators actually operate on.